# Sauf erreur vs sans faire erreur

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Ma langue maternelle est le français (Suisse) et aujourd'hui on m'a gentiment fait remarquer qu'on ne dit pas "sans faire erreur" mais qu'il s'agit de "sauf erreur".

Je me demandais si la première version serait tout de même acceptable ou si il s'agirait d'un régionalisme ou simplement une d'erreur de ma part.

Comment: Quel est votre contexte? Ecrit ou parlé?

Comment: parlé: "sanfairreur"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Sans faire d'erreur » est beaucoup plus utilisé, mais « sans faire erreur » est tout à fait correct en français de France ; ceci se voit dans cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sans+faire+erreur%2Csans+faire+d%27erreur&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csans%20faire%20erreur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20faire%20d%27%20erreur%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csans%20faire%20erreur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20faire%20d%27%20erreur%3B%2Cc0) et cette [page de recherche](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sans+faire+erreur%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=qLAZYZ7QIsG8aYS8iogE&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiexOD-o7TyAhVBXhoKHQSeAkEQ8tMDegQIARBB&biw=1920&bih=1007&dpr=1). Cependant, ces deux locutions ne sont pas synonymes ; « faire erreur » signifie « se tromper ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/erreur))  **Faire erreur**. Se tromper.
> ♦ Je vous dis que vous faites erreur.  (Duhamel, Jard. bêtes sauv.,1934, p. 79)

Si en présentant des données à quelqu'un vous dites « Ce sont les résultats, sans faire erreur. » vous n'utilisez pas la bonne forme, c'est bien « sauf erreur » qu'il faut dire dans ce cas. Ce que cela signifie,  c'est qu'il y a toujours la possibilité d'une erreur mais qu'autrement l'ensemble de données représente les résultats voulus.

- Ce sont les résultats, sauf erreur.
- (*même sens*) Ce sont les résultats, si je ne me trompe pas.

Si cependant vous voulez assurer la personne que ce que vous lui remettez est bien l'ensemble de résultats voulus, alors c'est correct.

- Vous pouvez dire à votre patron que ce sont les résultats, sans faire erreur.
- (*même sens*) Vous  ne vous tromperez pas en disant à votre patron que ce sont les résultats.